# Dataset recommendation, ordinal target variable

Tags: dataset, ranking

Does anyone have any recommendations for datasets with an ordinal target?

I'm currently using a rounded target from the Boston dataset.

```
from sklearn import  datasets
boston = datasets.load_boston()
X, y = boston.data, boston.target

y -= y.min()
y_ord = np.round(y)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are after, but Kaggle has many datasets you can use. You can use this search to get started:

https://www.kaggle.com/search?q=ordinal+datasetSize%3Asmall+datasetSize%3Amedium

another source:

https://www.gagolewski.com/resources/data/ordinal-regression/

Comment: Thanks! This will help greatly... Kaggle datasets usually have correlated features buried under high dimensional categorical/interaction features. It makes it a bit more difficult to test new models. But the other website seems perfect.